# trouble with freeing allocated memory in C

Tags: c, malloc

i created a linked list with those 2 structions

```
typedef struct dog {
   char *name;
   int age;
} dog;

typedef struct alist {
   dog* info;
   struct alist *next;
} alist;
```

whith those structions i made a linked list of dogs and it looks like this:
[image]
all the red bubbles are made with malloc.

im trying to create a function that removing all the list,dog type variables and freeing all allocated memory.
this is what i have tried:

```
void free_dogs(alist* al){

    if(al->next==NULL){
        free (al->info->name);
        free(al->info);
        free(al);
        return;
    }
    free_dogs(al->next);
    free(al->info->name);
    free(al->info);
    free(al);
    return;

}
```

the function navigate in the list as i wanted but its does not free the allocated memory and im not sure what is the reason.
after running this funtion only *name attribute are removed.

what am i doing worng?
hope its clear, thanks!

edit:
this is a picture of my debugger:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gm1Jq.png

the variable names are different becuase the example i gave are more simple, sorry for the mess.

so as you can see, after running the function i made not everything are removed.
*info pointing to allocated memory address
ID- still have content inside

Comment: How *precisely* did you determine that it didn't free the allocated memory?

Comment: i used eclipse debugger and also valgrind.

Comment: And what precisely did they tell you?

Comment: edited. hope its clear

Comment: Calling `free` won't change the value of the pointer.  It just won't be pointing to usable memory anymore.  Stick with Valgrind to see what's freed and what's not.

Comment: Sidenote: using recursion here is pretty awkward.

Comment: Please show us the code that creates the list. The problem may be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so as you can see, after running the function i made not everything are removed. *info pointing to allocated memory address ID- still have content inside

The implementation is not required to change the value or remove anything.

A common, and awesome, analogy is going back into a hotel room after you checked out of it. If you left a book on the desk, it might still be there. That doesn't mean you didn't check out correctly or that the room isn't available for someone else to check into it. It's just not *guaranteed* to be there anymore and only a fool would rely on it.